# Read CSV file with data separated by semicolons in C Code

Tags: c, csv

I have the following measurement data of format:

`40.0095;34.0;;0.065058;;392;300;;;;;;;;;;; 40.0242;;14.8;;;;;;392;300;400;300;20.0;0.0;0.0;-0.0;0.3;-0.3;1444;1494;392.9;18.6;299.7;-4.4`

and so on.

I tried reading the file using fscanf but it does not read the values. Instead records 0.0.

Here is my code:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>

double t_abs[700] ;
double t_nxtSIO[700] ;

int main( )
{
    FILE *filePointer ;
    
    filePointer = fopen("BallPlateLogData.txt", "r") ;

    if ( filePointer == NULL )
    {
        printf( "file failed to open." ) ;
    }
    else
    {
        int read = 0 ;
        int line = 0 ;
        
        printf("The file is now opened.\n") ;
        
        do{

        if (line != 0)
        {
            read = fscanf(filePointer,
                           "%lf[^;], %lf[^;]\n",
                            t_abs[line],
                            t_nxtSIO[line]) ;
        }

        line++ ;

        if (ferror(filePointer))
        {
            printf("Error reading file\n");
            return 1 ;
        }

        fclose(filePointer) ;
    
    printf("%0.1f\n", t_abs[line]) ;

    } while (!feof(filePointer)) ;
   
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

The above is not working.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: You don't show the definition of `t_abs`.  If it is an array of double, then you have undefined behavior that the compiler should warn you about.  Provide complete code and you may get more help.

Comment: Note that `file failed to open.` is the canonical example of a useless error message, and you've written it to the wrong stream.  Try `char *path = "Data.txt"; if( (filePointer = fopen(path, "r")) == NULL ){ perror(path); ...}`  `perror` writes the error message to the correct stream and includes useful information about why `fopen` failed (eg "permission denied" or "no such file or directory")

Comment: Yes. I had set `t_abs` to double. 
I have now updated the question with the complete code.

Comment: It's good that you are recording the value returned by `scanf`, but you never actually check the value so ... not so good.  There do not seem to be any commas in your input, so the commas in the format string are not going to match and `scanf` will never match more than one conversion specifier.  You would catch that if you check the value of `read`

Comment: Thank you for adding the code, and it is clear that you do have UB in the scanf calls.  The argument that corresponds to `%lf` should be a pointer to double, not a double.  The compiler should warn you about this.  Try `scanf("...", t_abs + line, ...)` or `scanf("...", &t_abs[line], ...`

Comment: It seems that you are only reading 2 fields.  In the input line `40.0242;;14.8;;;`, do you want the second field to be 0, or 14.8?  `scanf` is probably the wrong tool for this.  (Personal opinion: scanf is *always* the wrong tool, but some people seem to like it.)

Comment: Could you give an example of how I could check the value of read?

Comment: Yes I would like the second input to be zero in the cases that it is left blank. For now I am only reading two values to get the code to work. What other tool than `scanf` could I use?

Thank you for the replies

Comment: `if( read != 2 ) { ... }`.  If you want to treat consecutive semi-colons as a zero-entry, then it will be difficult with scanf.  Much simpler with `strtod`.  I'll post some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` is arguably good for reading formatted input.  If your input may contain empty fields, then it's not really formatted, and `scanf` is the wrong tool.  It may be possible to make `scanf` work, but it will be more difficult than it is worth.  Instead, you could read each line with `fgets` and parse the data with `strtod`.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                 
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                
#include <ctype.h>                                                                 
#include <string.h>                                                                
                                                                                   
double t_abs[700] ;                                                                
double t_nxtSIO[700] ;                                                             
                                                                                   
double                                                                             
parse_input(char *b, char **cursor, int line, int expect)                          
{                                                                                  
        char *start = *cursor;                                                     
        char **end = cursor;                                                       
                                                                                   
        double val = strtod(start, end);                                           
        while(isspace(**end)){  /* Skip over whitespace */                         
                *end += 1;                                                         
        }                                                                          
        if( **end != expect ){  /* Match the delimiter */                          
                fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected input in line %d:\n", line + 1);       
                fprintf(stderr, "%s", b);                                          
                while( b++ < *end ){                                               
                        putc(' ', stderr);                                         
                }                                                                  
                fprintf(stderr, "^^^^\n");                                         
                exit(1);                                                           
        }                                                                          
        *end += 1;         /* Move past the delimiter */                           
        return val;                                                                
}    
                                                                                   
int                                                                                
main(int argc, char **argv)                                                        
{                                                                                  
        FILE *filePointer ;                                                        
        char buf[1024];                                                            
        filePointer = argc > 1 ? fopen(argv[1], "r") : stdin;                      
        if( filePointer == NULL ) {                                                
                perror(argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "stdin");                              
                return 1;                                                          
        }                                                                          
        int line = 0 ;                                                             
        while( line < 700 && fgets(buf, sizeof buf, filePointer) != NULL ){        
                if( line != 0 ) {                                                  
                        char *cursor = buf;                                        
                        char *end;                                                 
                        t_abs[line] = parse_input(buf, &cursor, line, ';');        
                        t_nxtSIO[line] = parse_input(buf, &cursor, line, ';');     
                }                                                                  
                line += 1;                                                         
        }                                                                          
        fclose(filePointer) ;                                                      
        for( int i = 1; i < line; i += 1 ){                                        
                printf("%0.1lf  %0.1lf \n", t_abs[i], t_nxtSIO[i]) ;               
        }                                                                          
        return 0;                                                                  
}
```

This is written with the expectation that you will pass `'\n'` as the `expect` parameter for the last field of the input, but this won't work as is since the `isspace` will blow past the newline.  This is *exactly* the same type of problem you will have with `scanf`, so it might be a good exercise to figure out how to deal with it here in the explicit case.

Also note that arrays are zero-based, and it seems weird that you are writing data from the second line of input into the array at index 1 and not putting any data into the first position of the array (at index 0).  It would by more typical to put some data in the first position of the arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Where could I call the file from?

Yes I didn't realize I was starting from the second line of the data. Shall rectify that

Comment: What do you mean by "Where could i call the file from"?  If you build an executable, you can call it from anywhere by specifying the path, or you can put its base directory in your PATH and call it by its basename.  Just pass the path of the input file as the first argument, or redirect the input file to stdin.

Comment: I tried passing the path and the basename given that the file is in the same directory. It says `Unexpected input in line 2`

Comment: @kartiks77 Are you reading all of the fields?  As written, I would not expect this code to cleanly handle the last field of any line, and you'll need to make minor modifications.  This is a starting point.

Comment: Okay I shall try to get it to work. Thanks

Comment: The field that consists of just `-` is certainly going to be an issue.  I've modified the code so that the error message gives more context.  Note that this will not look pretty if you have any input lines longer than 1024 characters.  As an exercise for the reader; handle long lines gracefully.